# The Lost Fleet Book 1: Dauntless - which is the 2011 version?

Tags: the-lost-fleet

I am not concrete about it and I think some other people might be in the same position as well...

There is a re-issue of the "The Lost Fleet Book 1: Dauntless" from  Jack Campbell. Which is the original (2006) one and which the re-issue with the extras (2011). I am providing images of the covers from forbidden planet (UK)

A. [image: Dauntless A]

and

B. [image: Dauntless B]

They seem to have the same price in two sites I've checked (so it's not HC/Paperback)

Any ideas?

Comment: A big thanks to all of you, I have bought it and read it cover to cover. Will go to the next ones some point in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the 2006 edition, and it has cover B.

Comment: I think based on this we can identify the correct answer :-)

Comment: You can speculate on which one is the more recent pretty easily - There's no mention of the NYT best-selling list on the older one, and no publishing company would skip over that selling point!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [2006 cover release](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441014186), choice B in your question is the 2006 version.

This is the cover for the 2006 release:

[image: this is the 22006 cover]